# Django staff login to all urls

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I want to define some specific urls starts with /staff/* to access only by staff. So only staffs can access the urls starts with /staff/*

How can I define that in Django ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `user_passes_test` or `staff_member_required` decorator for the view that you associate with your url (that starts with `/staff/`), an example might be as follows:

**With `user_passes_test` decorator:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/some_url/')
def your_view(request, ...):
    # Only for staff
```

**With `staff_member_required` decorator:**

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def your_view(request, ...):
    # Only for staff
```

Comment: If I have 20 views for staff then I need to add this all the views. I think first answer is best.

Comment: I think you do the same with `login_required` decorator for views that require login. Of course, the solution with middlewares also is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Use a custom middleware. If the url starts with /staff/ and request.user is not staff, raise Http404 or return some special message to client.

Below is an example:

For django version < 1.10:

```
class StaffCheckMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        full_path = request.get_full_path()
        if full_path.startswith('/staff/') and not request.user.is_staff:
            raise Http404
```

For django version 1.10 or above:

```
class StaffCheckMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        full_path = request.get_full_path()
        if full_path.startswith('/staff/') and not request.user.is_staff:
            raise Http404

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Then add `StaffCheckMiddleware` in `settings.py`.

Comment: Error in Django 1.10.  in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: @KareshA It seems Django upgrades its middleware style in 1.10, I updated my answer for django 1.10, please check if it works for you.

Comment: Note that this is not as restrictive as @staff_member_required  which also ensures the user is active

Answer (score 0):

For class-based views I just took the LoginRequiredMixin in django source code and created a new mixin using this base:

> `website/utils/is_staff_mixin.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class IsStaffMixin(AccessMixin):
    """Verify that the current user has staff status."""
    def handle_no_permission(self, request):
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _("You need higher permissions in order to access this page."))
        return redirect("index")


    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _("You need to be logged in in order to access this page."))
            return redirect("login")
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            return self.handle_no_permission(request)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If the user is not logged in, I redirect to the login page. If the user is logged in but don't have the `is_staff` var set to `True`, I redirect to my homepage.

Here's a real world example:

> `website/apps/gallery/views.py`

```py
from website.utils.is_staff_mixin import IsStaffMixin
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

from .models import Gallery


class ListGalleriesView(IsStaffMixin, ListView):
    model = Gallery
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = "galleries"
    queryset = Gallery.objects.all().order_by("-date_added")


class GalleryView(IsStaffMixin, DetailView):
    model = Gallery
    context_object_name = "gallery"
```